# All compact genus 0 Riemann surfaces are isomorphic to a sphere

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Where can I read the proof that all Riemann surfaces which are homeomorphic to a sphere are also isomorphic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: Benedetti-Petronio: lectures of hyperbolic geometry, chapter $2$.